# JavaFX creating interactive map

Tags: javafx

I have got a problem to set up the interactive map. I want to make the visual feedback as the mouse is moved over the map to indicate to users what areas they can click on (e.g. the mouse cursor might change when over a clickable
area/town or the area might be highlighted/glow).

How can I achieve this?

[image: Map of 9 Regions]

Comment: Are you looking for a JavaFX equivalent of a [HTML image map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map)?  For example behavior is similar to this Wikipedia sample of ["The Club" image map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Club_(dining_club)) - click on the people in that image to see the interactive behavior.

Comment: If I understood right , similar. Application should display the map of Westeros on the main screen, and allow  to use the mouse to select a town/city/castle by clicking on it (or near to it!).
The application should then display information on the associated House in a new window. For instance,clicking on Winterfell would display information on House Stark, clicking on Highgarden would display information on House Tyrell, etc.

Comment: @ie2020 How can I contact ya ?

Comment: Do you want to contact with me John?

Comment: Yep I want ie2020

Comment: Could you possibly put this on github or somewhere to see the code? Very interested in seeing how it works. via @JustJayme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little bit difficult to answer because you do not tell us how your map is drawn and what you already know about the geometry shown on the map. If you only have a raster image of your map, e.g. scanned from a paper map, then things are getting complicated.
For a similar task I first wrote a program to geo-reference the map and determine the outlines of the interesting areas in the form of polygons.
Then I used the polygons to draw the outlines on the map display. I added listeners to each polygon so that I am notified when the mouse enters or exits an area.

Comment: This is a simple background jpg file

Comment: Probably to locate the coordinates of shapes I do not need to write the geo-refernce program and use the online service?

Comment: In your case you can skip the geo-referencing and simply use xy-coordinates instead. But there is no way arround the task to describe in some way where the relevant parts of your map are located. This can be anything from a simple circle to a large polygon. Once you have that it is easy to associate a mouse location with your geometry and take the appropirate actions.