# Highlighting the area on map

Tags: javafx

In relation to the previous question: [JavaFX creating interactive map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29132855/javafx-creating-interactive-map/29162795?noredirect=1#comment46600683_29162795I)`ve got the problem with fixing of highlighting area on the map. By decreasing of map size the highlighting area did not change the position, image here:http://s17.postimg.org/ucl64qun3/Capture.png How to fix that problem? Thanks for any help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again you did not tell us very much about how you achieved the scaling so my answer can only be a wild guess. I'd suggest to put your map and the geometry of the highlighting area into a Group and then scale the whole Group and not just the map.

Comment: Thanks Mipa! I attache the code here, may be it will be helpfull. http://codeviewer.org/view/code:4e59